# I am not getting value set offset in walmart API

Tags: walmart-api

"https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/items?offset=5&limit=20";

I want to get different offset items but i am getting always items with 0 index while i have set  starting offset value 5 in the walmart get all items api

Comment: Show example result and explain why you think it's wrong. Do you get different items returned, but starting from 0 index? That seems OK. But maybe in order to use offset/limit properly, you need to provide some sort order.

Comment: It's not just you.  I just tried and had the same results, no matter what value of offet I used.  I even tried adding includeDetails=true.

Comment: Show example result and explain why you think it's wrong. Do you get different items returned, but starting from 0 index? That seems OK. But maybe in order to use offset/limit properly, you need to provide some sort order. – underscore_d....................... i am not getting other items this is issue by this when i used other index value i get same items.

Comment: We are no longer supporting this API, this has been communicated long back. I request you to onboard into our new system https://walmart.io/onboarding